# How do you vertically center a custom image in a <li> element across browsers?

Tags: css

The design for the website I am working on calls for a custom image on lists instead of a bullet.  Using the image is fine, but I have been having difficulties ensuring that it is centered against the text of the list item across all browsers.  Does anyone know of a standard solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are referring to using a custom image bullet for your list this is the code you'll want to use, it will be vertically centered. I'm assuming here that the bullet image is 12px by 12px.

```css
ul li {
  background: transparent url(/link/to/custom/bullet.gif) no-repeat 0 50%; 
  padding-left: 18px; 
}
```

The only problem with this is that sometimes on long multi-line list items it looks odd. In that case it might be best to assign the background position to a slight indent from the top and the left (i.e. no-repeat 0 7px).

cheers, Bruce

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following code in your CSS file?

```css
li
{
   background-image: URL('custom.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: The custom bullet isn't the background image of a li element.

Answer (score 0):

set a specific line-height on the li element and a vertica align on the image.. worked for me

```css
li { height: 150px; line-height: 150px; }
li img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

and the HTML code

```
<li><img src="myimage.jpg" /></li>
```

if you want adapt the image to a custon size, preserving the ratio

```css
li img { max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px; width: auto; height: auto; }
```